# VBA: Prevent Excel from updating links on open

Tags: vba, excel

I have a workbook with multiple external links,

I don't want these to update when the workbook is opened, by me or any other user.

I have tried to achieve this with the simple work book open command below:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Workbook.UpdateLinks = xlUpdateLinksNever
End Sub
```

Am I missing something ?

Answer (score 0):

Put the code in the ThisWorkbook:

[image]

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Me.UpdateLink = xlUpdateLinksNever
End Sub
```